# Pole of a function and integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f = \frac{1}{z(a+\frac{z+1/z}{2})^2}$.

I have some question about the poles of this function.
Suppose we want $\int \frac{1}{z(a+\frac{z+1/z}{2})^2} dz$ following a circular path of radius one centred at the origin. Should we consider z=0 in the sum of the residues? I am asking that because, if we manipulate f, we got $f' = \frac{4z}{(2az+z^2+1)^2}$

But see, now z=0 is not a singularity, and so there is no pole. I am aware that $f\neq f'$, but if so, how to deal with the residue of f at z=0? I have no idea how to calc it, which makes me believe this singularity is removable or essential.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the notation $f'$ is not a good choice. I shall use $\varphi$ instead.

The result of your simplification is that, for each $z$ from the domain of $f$,$$f(z)=\frac{4z}{(2az+z^2+1)^2}=\varphi(z).$$But $\lim_{z\to0}\varphi(z)=0$, and therefore $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. And this impleas that $\operatorname{res}_{z=0}f(z)=0$. So, you can take $0$ into account and you also can not not take it into account. It makes no difference.